# Using for-each loop within a Fetch .then, to remove indexed array elements and retrieve sub-elements

Tags: javascript, api

I am learning javascript, trying out some things, but currently having an issue.

I am trying to work with an API. Essentially - the API endpoint returns an array and within the indexes there is the data in identical structure across each index element.

So for example, it looks like this:

`0-1000`

Then when I expand it out, they're like this:

```
0:
  param_1: 1
  param_2: 2
1:
  param_1: 3
  param_2: 4
2:
  param_1: 5
  param_2: 6
```

... and so on.

The data structure, as shown by the DevTools:

[image: Data structure]

The problem is - when I run the below code, I can print to console the top level array which returns the arrays named 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. OR I can also obviously give an array element and say `console.log(array[45])`.

But what I want to do is do a foreach to remove the top level index if this makes sense and just return the same parameter from each sub-array element. So for example, just return each and every `param_1` into a new array or to a console log.

My problem is, I've tried many things and I do not have enough understanding of all the complexities to make this work. I've tried a `.map`, or a for-each, but I think there are issues with promises not being fulfilled, etc. I also don't want to do a for-each on the whole of the API fetch which returns the original array.

The below code is what I'm working with and **what works**, and I will add in pseudocode further down what my intention is.

Working:

```
export const getWeatherData = (location) => {
  fetch(url, opts)
    .then(function (response) {
      document.querySelector(".loading").textContent = "";
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response;
    })
    .then(function (response) {

      const weatherData = {
        name: response.data.blah
      };
      console.log(weatherData.name);
      return weatherData;
    })
    .then(function (weatherData) {
      displayWeatherData(weatherData);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      err = displayError();
    });
};
```

Pseudocode:

```
export const getWeatherData = (location) => {
  fetch(url, opts)
    .then(function (response) {
      document.querySelector(".loading").textContent = "";
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response;
    })
    .then(function (response) {

      for each (item in response){
       add item.data.blah.param_1 to newarray.
       } 

      const weatherData = newarray

      console.log(weatherData);
      return weatherData;
    })
    .then(function (weatherData) {
      displayWeatherData(weatherData);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      err = displayError();
    });
};
```

I hope this makes sense, any questions, etc. or if you need clarity I will respond ASAP.

Comment: Could you please add data in structured form? Its unclear how you are getting the indexed elements.

Comment: @codinn.dev I've included an image which hopefully is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
const newarray = response.map((item) => {
  return item.data.blah.param_1;
});
```

This sould work for your problem. If there is sub arrays u can use forEach like this

```
const newarray = [];

response.forEach((item) => {
  item.data.blah.forEach((subItem) => {
    newarray.push(subItem.param_1);
  });
});

console.log(newarray);
```